# Is it possible to automatically launch a rocket (with satellite)?

Tags: factorio

The question is pretty self-explanatory. I have set up my factory in such way that it automatically creates a rocket and stuff a satellite in it. However, I still need to press the Launch button manually.

The [wiki page](https://wiki.factorio.com/index.php?title=Rocket_Silo) has no information on this specific detail, but on the forums I have found at least one mod which leads me to believe it is not possible.

So is it possible to automate launching a rocket in vanilla Factorio? Part of your answer should describe how so I can verify it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of the current **stable** release (version 0.14.23), this is not possible without the use of mods.

There appear to be a few mods which can do this - [Launch Control](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?f=93&t=15308) and [Auto Launch](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?f=92&t=18482). However I have not used either of these.

---

In the latest **experimental** releases (version 0.15.xx), a new option "auto-launch with satellite" has been added to the rocket silo, as described in [this developer blog](https://www.factorio.com/blog/post/fff-187).

> The rocket silo now has an auto-launch checkbox so you can launch them
>   automatically, and the launch is only going to happen when you insert
>   satellite.

The latest version 0.15 builds are publicly available as "experimental" releases, which you can download from the [website](https://www.factorio.com/download/experimental) (if you bought the game there), or by opting into Factorio beta releases on Steam (further details on how to do that [here](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=182912431)).

At the time of writing there is no word from the developers on when version 0.15 will be moved into the stable release branch.

Comment: Could you update your answer for 0.15?

Comment: I planned to do so when 0.15 is stable.

Comment: ...but it looks like people are adding answers for 0.15, so guess I should.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as of version 0.15 it is possible. See from the release page [here](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=44505)

Release notes include:

> •Added the ability to auto-launch the rocket.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: From the question: "Part of your answer should describe how so I can verify it."

Comment: @Vemonus I googled and found above link and picture. Is this what you are looking for

Comment: @Mathias711 it's not what I'm looking for -- OP specified they wanted to know how...

Comment: Actually... you do not need a mod for this...  This is available in vanilla as of 0.15 experimental.  You can verify the behavior visually.

Comment: Worth noting version 0.15 is not yet stable, so this feature is not available to players by default. Players have to manually to opt into the experimental releases in order to use this feature.